# using <tiles:insertAttribute inside <c:forEach

Tags: jsp, servlets, foreach, jstl, tiles

I am having a problem while using a nested tiles:insertAttribute tag inside c:forEach loop.

The c:forEach tag provides a var attribute which I want to use inside the tiles:insertAttribute but it turns to be not visible inside the tiles JSP:

tiles-defs.xml:

```
<definition name="orderDetail.content" template="/jsp/page/orderDetail.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="orderDetailCustomerInfo" value="orderDetail.customerInfo" />
    <put-attribute name="orderDetailShippingOrder" value="orderDetail.shippingOrder" />                         
</definition>   

<definition name="orderDetail.shippingOrder" template="/jsp/template/orderDetailShippingOrder.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="orderDetailShippingOrderLineItem" value="orderDetail.shippingOrderLineItem" />
</definition>
```

at orderDetail.jsp:

```
    <c:forEach items="${order.shippingOrderBeanCollection}" var="shippingOrder">    
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="orderDetailShippingOrder" />
    </c:forEach>
```

at orderDetailShippingOrder.jsp:

`${shippingOrder}` var is not visible inside the tile JSP.

I could find a "dirty" solution using c:set with scope request:

```
    <c:forEach items="${order.shippingOrderBeanCollection}" var="shippingOrder">
        <c:set var="shippingOrder" value="${shippingOrder}" scope="request" />

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="orderDetailShippingOrder" flush="true" />
    </c:forEach>
```

which seems to be a not so elegant solution.

I wonder what would be the best solution to make the var above visible inside the nested tile?